# Solidity large data handling

Tags: solidity, data

I’m currently doing a solidity project where users can create crowdfunding campaigns and others can participate financially to them.

Each campaign is defined by a struct containing basic informations like : owner address, title, current balance, category, target, deadline, img link.

But It also contains the description which can get quite long for a crowdfunding campaign as you can imagine.

For now I can display easily the campaigns on my website, using a getCampaigns function. But I’m sure that if the contract reach for example 100k campaigns, the getcampaigns returning 100k struct would be a nightmare.

How would you optimize this ? Use an external database that updates every time a user create a campaign ? Or maybe it would just work ?

And for the description, should I store it elsewhere, maybe offchain ? Because it would be nice if I could add image to them, which is not feasible for now

Comment: Have you considered content-addressable off-chain storage, e.g. IPFS? It gives you a guarantee of data integrity but isn't immediately available (nor should it be, by the sounds of it).

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, -Arran Schlosberg got it right when he recommended content-addressable off-chain storage solutions, there are some considerations to keep in mind, but for your use case storage solutions like SWARM or IPFS would be Ideal.